# python urllib2 - login and specify a form in page

Tags: python, web

I am trying to log in a forum using Python/URLLib2. But I can't seem to succeed. I think it might be because there are several form objects in the login page, and I submit the incorrect one (the same code worked for a different forum, with a single form).

Is there a way to specify which form to submit in URLLib2?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd try to sniff/track a real exchange between browser and the site; both Chrome and FF have tools for that. I'd also consider using [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) instead of raw urrlib2.

Comment: I see mechanize has the 'select-form' method. Is there a compatible for URLLib2?

Answer (score 1):

Here i can give you the steps to achieve your goal:

1. Read the page using urllib2
2. parse the page into a dom object ( see xml.dom.minidom.parsestring or other equivalent)
3. search if the page has the login form by serching form id etc.
4. if form is there, create the form click using code (create http headers, response data). and post the information using urllib2 http methods ( GET or POST or for Ajax, with extra header as documented at [w3c school](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp))

Comment: @ido i replied to your question "python urllib2 - login and specify a form in page" that heading suggested u were confident with raw urllib2 and started to sink with it :), i came for help. now u wrote a response suggesting "This is the answer - mechanize is really easy to use and supports multiple forms." 

for me i welcome both ur question and the answer u arrived :) for me accomplishing it with the constraint was easy enough. and a 15 mins job. Cheers !!!!

Answer (score 0):

9000 said: "I'd try to sniff/track a real exchange between browser and the site; both Chrome and FF have tools for that. I'd also consider using mechanize instead of raw urrlib2"

This is the answer - mechanize is really easy to use and supports multiple forms.

Thanks!